# On hover change all with same id with style 1 while changing the hovered div with style 2

Tags: javascript, css

I have some dynamic user generated divs. 
I'm trying to create a function so when the user hovers on one of the divs it highlights while the other divs get blurred.

Therefore I need to figure out how (if possible) I can change the hovered div with one style while changing all the others with another style.

The generated divs are simply spawn through php as a simple div looking like this:

```
  <div class="usercontainer" id="usercontainer"> </div>
```

I have tried something like this to change the div the user hovers on. But I can't figure out how I at the same time can change all the others. 
Do I need javascript for it? or can it be done with css alone?

```
 .usercontainer:hover 
  {

   background-color: red;
    opacity: 1.0;  
    }
```

Comment: Why not just have anything that's not hovered on be blurry and then just unblur the one that's hovered on? Or is there a different purpose you didn't mention?

Comment: I'm hoping they **don't** all have the same ID since that's invalid HTML.

Comment: CSS won't help here since it can't select UP the DOM so anything before the hovered div wouldn't be affected, JS would be **much** simpler.

Comment: @FeaturedSpace I'm not looking for that. As I have mentioned I need the one hovered on to be highlight and the others to be blurred when the user hovers.

Comment: @Paulie_D I didn't know that! Thank you.  I will add a growing variable for each spawn of div, so they all get a different id.

Comment: are your `<div>s` on the same level or they are descendants?

Answer (score 3):

I am sharing with css approach only, though you can do it by adding a class at parent with `javascript`.

Disadvantage of this approach is you have to use `!important` to override child styles.

```css
.children {
    display: inline-block;
 height: 100px;
 width: 100px;
 background-color: grey;
 color: red;
 font-size: 50px;
 border: solid 1px yellow;
}

.parent:hover .children {
 opacity: 0.2;
}

.children:hover {
 opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="children">1</div>
    <div class="children">2</div>
    <div class="children">3</div>
    <div class="children">4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This would certainly be one option but I'm not sure it's precisely what the OP has in mind.

Comment: I think this is precisely what OP wanted in terms of behavior. Styling is up to him to do whatever he wants afterwards. There is just the problem with someone hovering in the blank spaces and everything becoming gray-ish but that's fixable.

Comment: This works almost perfectly! Except that I'm not interested in everything getting blurred if the user hovers on the "parent". It should only happen if the user hovers on one of the "children" in your example. Does that make sense? I'm sorry if I have formulated my question poorly.

Comment: @Exactly Jose, but how would you "fix" that? because its' a big problem to my application.